# Insist (that) something should be done

Tags: subjunctives, optional-that, irrealis-mood

[Fowler reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA418&ots=nmQu8zdftQ&dq=%22you%20can%20insist%20that%20something%20be%20done%20(subjunctive%20with%20that%20optionally%20omitted)%20or%20that%20something%20should%20be%20done%22&hl=es&pg=PA418#v=onepage&q=%22you%20can%20insist%20that%20something%20be%20done%20(subjunctive%20with%20that%20optionally%20omitted)%20or%20that%20something%20should%20be%20done%22&f=false)

> You can **insist** *that* something be done (subjunctive with *that*
> optionally omitted) or *that* something **should** be done.

Isn't *that* also optional in the version with **should** then?

Comment: You might want to un-italicize the second "that" to match the source (I can't make such a small edit myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these the options? It's clearer if you write out the choice
instead of bundling them together.

> You can insist (that) something be done...

> You can insist (that) something should be done...

also...

> You may say (that) something should be done...

In any case, "that" is optional.